# How do I insert a line above specific lines in a file using Vim or Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, vim, sed

I'd like to insert the line

```
<hr />
```

above every occurrence of a header 2 line in a file - e.g., above this pattern

```
<h2>variable pattern here</h2>
```

So the above should become

```
<hr />
<h2>variable pattern here</h2>
```

How can I do this with Vim, Sed or Perl?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `sed` you could do `sed '/<h2>/i <hr />'`:

```
$ cat file
<html>
<h2>variable pattern here</h2>
<h3>not here</h3>
<h2>heading</h2>
<h2>Something</h2>

$ sed '/<h2>/i <hr />' file
<html>
<hr />
<h2>variable pattern here</h2>
<h3>not here</h3>
<hr />
<h2>heading</h2>
<hr />
<h2>Something</h2>
```

The first part `/<h2>/` matches line containing `<h2>` and the second part uses the `i` command to insert `<hr />` above the matched line.

A nice option with `sed` is `-i` this save the changes back to the file instead of printing to `stdout` but be sure that the changes are correct first.

```
sed -i '/<h2>/i <hr />' file
```

Comment: Could you explain how that works, i.e. what the `/i` does, please?

Comment: Will do, but have to wait another 6 minutes

Answer (score 16):

vim way:

cmd `:g/<h2>/normal O<hr />`  will do the job.

see it here: (I took the example from sudo_O)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

One of the many ways to do that in Vim:

```
:g/h2/norm O<hr /><CR>
```

Breakdown:

1. `:g[lobal]` acts on every line that match a pattern, see `:h :global`.
2. `h2` the pattern we are looking for, it could be made a bit smarter, probably.
3. `norm[al]` runs a *normal* mode command, see `:h :normal`.
4. `O` opens a new line above the current line and enters *insert* mode.
5. `<hr />` is what you want to insert.
6. We hit `<CR>` (`<RETURN>`) to run the whole thing.

Another way, using a single substitution:

```
:%s/^\s*<h2/<hr \/>\r&<CR>
```

Breakdown:

1. `:%s[ubstitute]/` performs the substitution on every line of the buffer, see `:h :s`.
2. `^` anchors the pattern to the beginning of the line.
3. `\s*` matches any number (0 to many) of white space characters. It is not strictly needed if you are sure that all your HTML tags are on column 1.
4. `<h2` is the pattern we are really looking for.
5. `<hr />` is what we want to insert.
6. Since we want it to be on its own line, it is followed by a `\r`,
7. and, finally, the matched text, `&`.

Answer (score 3):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;

tie my @file, 'example.html'
  or die "Unable to tie file: $!";

@file = map { m!<h2>.*</h2>!
            ? ( "<hr />", $_ )
            : $_ } @file;

untie @file;
```

Answer (score 3):

Command line solution in Perl.

```
perl -i~ -p -e'/<h2>/ and $_ = "<hr />\n$_"' your_file.html
```

Explanation of command line flags:

- **-i** In-place editing (replace existing file), back-up to your_file.html~
- **-p** Print each line in the file
- **-e** Code to execute for each line in the file

If the line contains  (`/<h2>/`) then prepend `<hr />` to it (the current line is in $_).

But have you considered if this is the best approach? If you want to add a line above every H2 element, then perhaps you should do that with CSS?

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -plne 'print "<hr />" if(/\<h2\>variable pattern here\<\/h2\>/)' your_file
```

Input file:

```
> cat temp
<h2>variable pattern here</h2>
1
<h2>variable pattern here</h2>
2
<h2>variable pattern here</h2>
3
4
<h2>variable pattern here</h2>
```

Now the execution

```
> perl -plne 'print "<hr />" if(/\<h2\>variable pattern here\<\/h2\>/)' temp
<hr />
<h2>variable pattern here</h2>
1
<hr />
<h2>variable pattern here</h2>
2
<hr />
<h2>variable pattern here</h2>
3
4
<hr />
<h2>variable pattern here</h2>
```

This will just output to the console.
If you want to change it inplace:

```
perl -pi -lne 'print "<hr />" if(/\<h2\>variable pattern here\<\/h2\>/)' your_file
```

Comment: There's never a reason to use both `-p` and `-n`. You want `-p` here. And I can't see that `-l` is doing anything useful here either. Also your regex is far more complex than it needs to be :-/